# Tinymce error can not call uniqueId of undefined

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm using jquery version of tinymce
I used it earlier and worked fine but now it isn't working anymore

my code is :

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '../js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,|,bullist,numlist,|,hr,|,link,unlink,image,|,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,


        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

    });
```

and it shows error :

---

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'uniqueId' of undefined

any idea, how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Mazhar, I tried your code using TinyMCE 3.5 with JQuery 1.5.1 on Safari, Firefox and IE8 with no error. What environment are you seeing this in?

Comment: when I tried this on a blank page it worked fine, but when I placed it in project it didn't work. I'm using iButton, ajax upload with it.